# Interface as Dependency Property - Converter Failed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have this dependency property in my custom control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoCompleteServiceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
                         "AutoCompleteService", 
                         typeof(IAutoCompletable),
                         typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox),
                         new PropertyMetadata(new CommonSubstringSuggestion()));
```

When I bind this to my view model property (type of `IAutoCompletable`) I have binding error:

> Error: Converter failed to convert value of type
>   'WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AutoCompleteTextBoxControl.Algorithm.LevenshteinDistance,
>   WinRTXamlToolkit, Version=1.5.4.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' to type 'IAutoCompletable'; BindingExpression:
>   Path='AutoCompleteAlgorithm'
>   DataItem='WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample.ViewModels.Controls.AutoCompleteTextBoxTestsViewModel,
>   WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample, Version=1.5.4.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is
>   'WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.AutoCompleteTextBox' (Name='null'); target
>   property is 'AutoCompleteService' (type 'IAutoCompletable').

LevenstheinDistance is implementing `IAutoCompletable` so why does such conversion fails?

Comment: Perhaps the same problem as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10544084/1136211). Try changing `typeof(IAutoCompletable)` to `typeof(object)`.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544084/winrt-dependencyproperty-with-ienumerable-not-firing-at-all/26023517#26023517 There are 2 solutions for this bug in the framework.