# WinRT DependencyProperty is never set

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-runtime, dependency-properties

I have some issues with my `DependencyProperty` in a custom `UserControl`.

I need to display informations about people in a particular way. To achieve this, I have several `UserControls` that receive a `List<PeopleList>` which contains (obviously) one or more People.

Let me show you my (simplified) code and I'll then explain to you the actual behavior of my app.

Here is my UserControl :

```
public abstract class PeopleLine : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PeopleListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PeopleList", typeof(List<PeopleModel>), typeof(PeopleLine), new PropertyMetadata(default(List<PeopleModel>)));

    public List<PeopleModel> PeopleList
    {
        get { return (List<PeopleModel>)GetValue(PeopleListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PeopleListProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then my xaml :

```
<local:PeopleLine
    x:Class="MyApp.Controls.EventSheet.OnePeople"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Controls.EventSheet"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid
        Margin="0 5"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="51">
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="Red"
            FontSize="25"
            Text="{Binding PeopleList[0].Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</local:PeopleLine>
```

And this all starts with my `Page` which contains an `ItemsControl` with a correct `ItemsSource` (I already checked it) and an `ItemTemplateSelector` (also working perfectly). Here is one of the `DataTemplate` used by the selector :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OnePeople">
    <peoplecontrols:OnePeople
        PeopleList="{Binding LinePeopleList}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm using several Models That are not really important here since I simplified my code to only have the most important information.

So, back to my issue. When replacing the `peoplecontrols:OnePeople` in the selector's DataTemplate by a string and putting `LinePeopleList[0].Name`as `Text`, I have the correct text displayed, proving me that my data is correct at this point.
Problem is that when putting back my `peoplecontrols:OnePeople`, my `DependencyProperty` is never set. I put a breakpoint at PeopleList's setter and it never triggers.

I tried several modifications (especially those that are given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544084/winrt-dependencyproperty-with-ienumerable-not-firing-at-all), so replacing the `typeof(List<PeopleModel>)`by `typeof(object)` has already been tried) with no success. Also, I tried to replace my `DependencyProperty` to a `string` and directly send the name in the `DataTemplate` but the setter is still not called...

I have no more ideas now and don't understand what's wrong with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line in your **UserControl's Constructor**, after the call to InitializeComponent:

```
(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
```

I created a sample app on regarding this. Hopefully it reflects your situation correctly:

https://github.com/mikoskinen/uwpusercontrollistdp

If you clone the app and run it, you'll notice that the binding doesn't work. But if you uncomment the Datacontext = this line from UserControl, everything should work OK. Here's working code:

```
    public PeopleLine()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: Man this solution is pretty elegant! I found another one which is doing the exact same thing, I name my UserControl (like `x:Name="Parent"` for example) and then, in my root view, I set the DataContext like that: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Parent}"`. Thanks for your answer though :)